# AS3 Using a custom event to change property of different class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In the game that I am making, you choose a shape, and then on the next screen choose a color. The shape selector works fine and loads one of 6 'shape' movie clips into the next stage of the game. On this stage, I have buttons to control color. Im trying to make the buttons change the color of the movieclip by launching a custom event. This would then be detected by a listener within the class for each movieclip.

So far this is my code:

The screen that contains the color change button:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class ColorSelector extends MovieClip
    {

        public function ColorSelector() 
        {

            charcoal.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickCharcoal );
        }


        public function onClickCharcoal (mouseEvent:MouseEvent): void
        {
            dispatchEvent (new ColorEvent (ColorEvent.CHARCOAL) );
            trace ("click")
        }}
```

The custom event class:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class ColorEvent extends Event
    {
        public static const CHARCOAL:String = "charcoal";

        public function ColorEvent( type: String )
        {
            super ( type );
        }
    }}
```

The movieclip being acted upon:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;


    public class Gobbert extends MovieClip {


        public function Gobbert() 
        {
            this.addEventListener (ColorEvent.CHARCOAL, makeCharcoal)
        }


        public function makeCharcoal (colorEvent: ColorEvent) :void
        {
            this.alpha = .5
        }
    }
```

It seems to me like the event is not getting through to the class with the listener. I could really use a fresh pair of eyes to help me figure out whats going on. The program doesn't give me any error, just doesn't do much else either.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the bubbles parameter on the constructor. If omitted it defaults to false. The call to super on the custom event should be:

```
super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
```

You will want to pass bubbles in as true via addEventListener function call or hard code inside the custom event constructor.

Also make sure the target (instance of Gobbert) movie clip is on the event bubbling path which means the ColorSelector has to be a child of the display list of Gobbert. If your display list is not set up this way you may want to rethink your approach and have the event propagate from the selector to a common parent and then set the color on Gobbert through that common parent.